# Using UUID in JMeter for Post Data

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have to perform load test using JMeter on POST REST API which send JSON data in the request body as follows

```
{
  id="",
  name="abc",
  age="34"
 }
```

I want to use UUID feature in JMeter to auto generate UUID for the value of "id" which should be unique for every record created in the backend.

The value for "id" should be unique for every Thread executed in that Thread Group in JMeter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use [__UUID](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function

```
  {
    id="${__UUID}",
    name="abc",
    age="34"
   }
```

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.